# How to plot a meta::metagen() object using meta::forest() and have squaresize corresponding to weights in R?

Tags: r, r-forestplot

```r
# sample data
data <- tibble::tibble(
    TE = c(0.95, 1.2),
    seTE = c(0.25, 0.5),
    studlab = c("A", "B"))

# run meta-analysis
ma <- meta::metagen(
    TE = TE, 
    seTE = seTE, 
    studlab = studlab, 
    data = data)

# get weights of each study
weights <- meta:::weights.meta(ma) %>%
    tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(rscale = w.random / max(w.random)) %>% 
    dplyr::pull(rscale)

# make forest plot
meta::forest(ma, squaresize = weights)
```

this got following error message

```
Error: Argument 'squaresize' must be a numeric of length 1.
```

it seems that meta::forest can only output fixed-size squarebox when input is a metagen object....